# When should we consider "reverse Heisenberg" evolution of operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, time-evolution

In Quantum Mechanics, the Heisenberg evolution of an observable $\hat{o}$ is defined as

$$ \hat{o}(t) = U(t,0)^{\dagger} \hat{o} U(t,0) $$

where $U(t,0)$ is the unitary time-evolution operator from time $0$ to time $t$. This satisfies the Heisenberg equations of motion

$$ i\hbar \frac{d}{dt} \hat{o}(t) = [\hat{o}(t),H(t)],$$

But is there a standard name for the "reverse Heisenberg evolution"

$$ \hat{o}_R(t) = U(t,0) \hat{o} U(t,0)^{\dagger} $$

which satifies the differential equation
$$ i\hbar \frac{d}{dt} \hat{o}_R(t) = [H(t),\hat{o}_R(t)],$$

and in which circumstances should one consider it?

It came up because I was thinking about a state $|\psi\rangle$ which is defined to be the (unique, say) eigenstate of some observable $\hat{o}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then we see that the time-evolved state $|\psi(t)\rangle = U(t,0) |\psi\rangle$ can be characterized as the eigenstate of the operator $\hat{o}_R(t)$.

Comment: $U(t,0)^\dagger = U(0,t)$, the unitary time-evolution operator from time t to time 0.

Comment: @octonion Yes, but I'm not sure how that addresses my question?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is then. What you wrote with flipped conjugation signs is no different than the standard time evolution. Why does it deserve a new name?

Comment: @octonian It's not the same time evolution. Maybe this is clearer in differential form (which I added in the question). The two differential equations are evidently defining two different time-dependent families of operators if you start from the same operator at time $t=0$.

Comment: The first differential equation also defines operator times earlier than $t=0$. The only difference with the second equation is you flipped the sign of t. It represents the same evolution

Comment: @octonion I am considering cases where the Hamiltonian is time-dependent (and not necessarily symmetric around $t=0$). In such cases, you cannot turn one differential equation into the other simply by flipping the sign of $t$.

Comment: Nevermind, I see your point. It is different.

Comment: I am confused: You admitted you are using it for $H(t)\neq H(-t)$ hamiltonians. So you *mapped* your problem to the usual one with a time-reversed Hamiltonian. What is the question?

Comment: @Cosmas The question is under what circumstances it makes sense to discuss the second evolution in the context where H(t) is not the time-reversed one but rather the original one. I have an example of that in the question.

Comment: A few quick observations: 

(1) You can consider time evolution as an algebra automorphism $\alpha_t(O) = U(t,0)^\dagger O U(t,0)$.  Then the inverse $\alpha_t^{-1}$ is exactly what you have.

(2) Probably something like this shows up in OTOC / Keldysh contour computations.

Comment: As a follow up to (1), this means that you could interpret $o_R(t)$ as the (non-local, messy) operator that will end up as $o(0)$ under a *forward* time-evolution of length $t$.

Answer (score 0):

> It came up because I was thinking about a state $|\psi\rangle$ which is defined to be the (unique, say) eigenstate of some observable $\hat{o}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then we see that the time-evolved state $|\psi(t)\rangle = U(t,0) |\psi\rangle$ can be characterized as the eigenstate of the operator $\hat{o}_R(t)$

This property is necessary for the derivation of the path integral in quantum mechanics and QFT. In the context I saw it, it was used in reverse, but it's the same idea. We had operators which evolve normally
$$X(t) = U^\dagger (t)X U(t)$$
$$P(t) = U^\dagger (t)P U(t)$$

but states were then defined with backwards evolution:
$$|x,t\rangle \equiv U^\dagger (t)|x\rangle$$

So that for all time, they remain eigenstates:

$$X(t)|x,t\rangle=U^\dagger (t)X U(t) U^\dagger(t)|x\rangle$$
$$=U^\dagger (t)x |x\rangle$$
$$=x |x,t\rangle$$
(and same with $P$)

If you want to read more, I learned this from Weinberg's *The Quantum Theory of Fields*, the part he does this is in Chapter 9.1, page 379. His derivation is for Quantum Mechanics but with n degrees of freedom. Taking the $n\to \infty$ would give the QFT path integral.

You asked if this evolution has a name; I don't know of any special name for it. Reverse evolution seems to get the point right.